# How to return a list of extends wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method

```
public List<? extends FooInterface<X,Y>> getList()
```

in a class that has as a member a list:

```
List<FooImplementation> foolist = new ArrayList<>();
```

and i'm trying to do something like:

```
public List<? extends FooInterface<X,Y>> getList(){
    return foolist;
}
```

but it does not work.

The error is :

```
Incompatible types. 
Required List<? extends FooInterface<X,Y>> 
Found List<FooImplementation>.
```

What is wrong with it? I also tried to copy the foolist into a list of extends wildcards but that proved to be a fool's errand.

Comment: How did you declare the class `FooImplementation` ?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I had to declare it like: List<FooImplementation<X,Y>> to work.

Comment: @CioroiuAdrian-Nicu could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I just saw the request for posting the solution.

So basically what I did was to add the generic parameters  to the type of the list.

Instead of :

```
List<FooImplementation> foolist = new ArrayList<>();
```

I used :

```
List<FooImplementation<X,Y>> foolist = new ArrayList<>();
```

which worked because I declared the `FooImplementation` class like this:

```
class FooImplementation<X,Y> implements FooInterface<X,Y>{...}
```

And now everything works perfectly, no errors.
Thank ann of those who spared the time to answer/comment on my question.

Comment: btw, is it ok for me to accept my own answer or this constitutes a moral grey area similar to liking your own facebook posts :D ? I'm asking because the subject is not covered bu the FAQ